# Powershell WMI WQL Query

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, event-log, wql

I am trying to create a permanent event subscription that executes a power shell script when a USB device is plugged in (event code 2006), however for some reason it won't run when it should, or at all.

i am almost certain the code that is the issue is here:

```
#Filter for WMI instance
$wmiParams.Class = '__EventFilter'
$wmiParams.Arguments = @{
Name = 'EventLogFilter'
EventNamespace = 'root\CIMV2'
QueryLanguage = 'WQL'
Query = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' AND TargetInstance.LogFile='Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational' AND TargetInstance.EventCode=2006"

Try{
    If($CheckFilterExists -eq $null){
        $filterResult = Set-WmiInstance @wmiParams
        $result = "FilterResult instance was successfully set."
        $result | Out-File $file -Append
        } 
     Else{
        $result = "FilterResult has already been created."
       $result | Out-File $file -Append
      }
   }
Catch [system.exception]{
   $catch = "A fatal error occured when setting the filter instance."
   $catch += $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message 
   $catch | Out-File $file -Append
}
```

I have tested every other key segment of code, so hopefully the issue is in this bit.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there some code before/after this? It seems incomplete.

Comment: Sorry, the code is quite long so I am trying to figure out how much is needed, added the try catch that adds the filter